# Can't update Realm.io Object with primary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have this issue.

```
  ApiKeyModel *credentials = [[ApiKeyModel allObjects] firstObject];
  RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
  [realm beginWriteTransaction];
  credentials.current_uuid = self.currentExecutionUuid;
  [realm commitWriteTransaction];

  ApiKeyModel *credentialsUpdated = [[ApiKeyModel allObjects] firstObject];
  NSLog(@"print curren execution %@", [credentialsUpdated current_uuid]);
```

I'm trying to update the apikeymodel object then when I print the updated value return nil, the ApiKey model object has a primary key, but is not the value I am trying to update.

Comment: Do you create `ApiKeyModel` objects somewhere else in your code?

Comment: only in the login , but at this point no other thread or class is working with that object

Comment: also the self.currentExecutionUuid property is a NSString and not nil

Comment: When you set `credentials.current_uuid = self.currentExecutionUuid;`, write a log to see if it exists and it's being updated.

Comment: already find the problem, the set is not using the right property ! you help me a lot thanks!